# How to pass inputs from one function to another using .apply method?

Tags: javascript

For my assignment, I have to read 3 inputs. Once I have the input, I have to pass them as arguments to the addNewPost function. I understand that I have to use the .apply function, however, I am confused on how to do this even after looking at various sources online.

```
function handleFormSubmit() {

    var username = document.getElementById("input-username").value,
        password = document.getElementById("input-password").value,
        picture = document.getElementById("input-picture").value;

    addNewPost.apply(this, arguments);
}

function addNewPost(username, img_src, caption) {

}
```

Am I correctly reading the inputs, and if I am, how do I pass them as arguments to addNewPost?

Comment: Is using the `apply` a requirement ? otherwise how have you come to the conclusion you need to use it ?

Comment: Why not `addNewPost(username, password, picture)`

Comment: the variables will have to be part of this `this.username =`, `this.password =`, etc.

Comment: While apply is not a requirement, it is the method that seemed most apparent when researching online. However, I am only required to pass them as arguments to the function.

Comment: You just have to invoke the addNewPostFunction function with the the variables you've declared inside handleFormSubmit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using `apply` is not a requirement, you can simply pass them into the function;

```
addNewPost(username, password, picture);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fill an array with your form data (parameters for your function)...

```
var args = [
        document.getElementById("input-username").value,
        document.getElementById("input-picture").value,
        document.getElementById("input-password").value
    ];

    addNewPost.apply(this, args);
```